# Generate PDF from HTML string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, pdf-generation

So, I am trying to generate PDF file by passing the HTML string to the server to generate the byte streams using NReco library http://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx and return it back to the client side however, after I converted to blob format and save it with FileSaver library https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/, the saved file is unable to open.

Below are my code by far:

controller

```
        string HtmlContent = model.HtmlContent;


        string PageType = gradeReportPdfBindingModel.PageType;
        string FileName = gradeReportPdfBindingModel.FileName;

        var pdfDoc = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PageType))
            pdfDoc.Orientation = PageOrientation.Default;
        else
        {
            if (PageType == "Landscape")
                pdfDoc.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
            else
                pdfDoc.Orientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
        }
         var pdfBytes = pdfDoc.GeneratePdf(HtmlContent);
         HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(pdfBytes);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = FileName;
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

        return result;
```

Customer.js

```
 Customer.Export(exportModel).then(function (response) {
            var file = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            saveAs(file, fileName);
        });
```

HTTP POST call

```
   Export: function (model) {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    accept: 'application/pdf'
                },
                url: appSettings.serverPath + '/customer/export',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                data: $.param(model),
            });
        },
```

Response log from browser console:

```
Object { data: "%PDF-1.4 1 0 obj << /Title (��) /Cr…", status: 200, headers: ed/<(), config: Object, statusText: "OK" }
```

Edit 1:
I tried to return the result as HttpResponseMessage. How can I consume it on javascript side?

Edit 2:
I figured it out. This is how I do it.
  Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("export")]
    public IHttpActionResult GeneratePdf(model)
    {
     var pdfBytes = pdfDoc.GeneratePdf(HtmlContent);

        var policy = new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(300), Priority = CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable };
        var cacheId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        MemoryCache.Default.Add("pdfBytes_" + cacheId, pdfBytes, policy);

        return Ok(cacheId);
  }

  [Authorize]
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("getPdf/{cacheId}/{fileName}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage DownloadPdf(Guid CacheId, string FileName)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        try
        {
            var pdfBytes = (Byte[])MemoryCache.Default.Get("pdfBytes_" + CacheId);
            MemoryCache.Default.Remove("pdfBytes_" + CacheId);

            using (MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes))
            {
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(memorystream.ToArray());
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = FileName;
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
                return response;
            }
        }
```

customer.js:

```
    Customer.Export(model).then(function (response) {
            Customer.DownloadPdf(response.data, fileName).then(function (response) {
                var file = new Blob([response.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
                saveAs(file, fileName);
            }).catch(function (response) {
                console.error('Error', response.status, response.data);
            });

        });
```

Http calls:

```
   Export: function (model) {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: appSettings.serverPath + '/customer/export',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                data: $.param(model),
            });
        },
        DownloadPdf: function (cacheId, fileName) {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    accept: 'application/pdf'
                },
                responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                url: appSettings.serverPath + '/customer/downloadPdf/' + cacheId + '/' + fileName,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/pdf' }
            });
        }
```

I basically tested it on my local dev machine and it works, but when I published it Azure Web App, I was unable to get through the POST call and it returns status 500 after some time. Not sure why, but I am suspecting the MemoryCache I am using. Any idea will be appreaciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I used `iTextSharp` library for pdf generation from html. If you don't find a great solution for this, consider using that. It was easy to use.

Comment: @MeghVidani Thanks for replying, I tried iTextSharp library and the saved pdf still unable to open. Probably due to how I handle the byte-stream on the client side. Any idea?

Comment: where have you defined `pdfBytes` in the above code?

Comment: I think `var pdfBytes = pdfDoc.GeneratePdf(htmlContent);` is missing in your code!

Comment: @MeghVidani My bad, I accidentally deleted it when I editing my code. Please see my latest edit. Thanks